# Keeping a DCOM object alive from Java server on a REST invocation

Tags: java, com, rest, ejb, dcom

I'm implementing a REST API for my Java server. One of the of the resources obtained through the API is actually creating a C++ DCOM object and reflecting its values.
The Java to COM bridge I'm using is J-Integra.

The problem is that I need to keep that DCOM object alive for subsequent REST calls, but the object is alive just as long as its Java reference is - which is until the REST session expires at most.

How can I keep the DCOM object alive until I no longer needs it?
The only thing I thought of till now was using an EJB which then will be the one to initiate the DCOM object and hold its reference. I'm not an expert on EJBs, but I think that a) its an overkill solution b) the EJB may be cached (passiviate?) by the server, losing the DCOM reference at that.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Inbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I keep the DCOM object alive
>   until I no longer needs it?

I guess that depends on what it means to no longer need the object.  How do you know when you're done with it?

Are these DCOM instances applicable site-wide, or just for a specific user?  If site-wide, is it possible for the resource that is receiving these requests to keep a reference to that object?  If not, perhaps you need Yet Another Layer to manage those objects for you.

What framework are you using for REST?

---

> Here's some more info: The DCOM object
>   is executing a set of tasks async. So,
>   the main call to it from the Java
>   server returns immidietialy, while the
>   DCOM object continues execution.
>   Unfortuantley, it's quite an old
>   object and i have no control over its
>   implementation or interface - I can't
>   change that. The DCOM object doesn't
>   even have COM events. The only way to
>   know if it is done or not, is to poll
>   it using a specific method
>   (getStatus). I don't want to poll it
>   from my REST API implementation, as
>   this will break the REST concept. I
>   have no way to know in advance how
>   long it will take for the DCOM object
>   to run, so I can't keep the session
>   alive that long.

So basically, you want to use a REST call to start an operation but don't care when it finishes or what its status is?  If so, can you start a Thread that will start the DCOM operation, poll the status until the operation is deemed to be complete and then destroy the DCOM operation?

Comment: The thread direction seems like a possibility.

Wouldn't the thread be destructed when the session is?

Comment: @Inbar, No, it would just run as a separate thread in the server process.

Answer (score 0):

Place the component registered at COM+, and it stay alive. Check more info at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503740/how-to-force-process-isolation-for-an-out-of-process-com-server/512327#512327).