# Cannot instanciate a NotesUIWorkspace from VBA (Word)

Tags: vba, lotus-notes, ms-word, lotusscript

The source situation: I have an Notes Application which uses MS Office 2000 under Windows XP. The new situation has to be MS Office 2010 under Windows 7. IBM Notes is 8.5.3FP3.
The old one uses a VBA template to communicate with Notes which works properly. At one time a Notes.NotesUiWorkSpace object is created to open a document, navigate to a richtext item, select all the content (formatted) and copy to the clipboard. Then the clipboard content ist pasted into the Word document via VBA. That works fine.
The same code in the second environment doesn't work anymore. I noticed that the Notes.NotesUIWorkSpace object cannot be instanciated in VBA. No errors, no hints. Only the runtime error when I reference the workspace-object later.

Here is a code excerpt:

```
' this is a profile document which is filled correctly
Call prof.Save(True, True)
Call prof.replaceItemValue("Form", "Profile")
' setting up the ui
dim WS as Object
set WS = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUiWorkSpace")
Set uiprof = WS.EditDocument(True, prof)

' Set uiprof = WS.currentDocument
If uiprof.editMode Then Call uiprof.gotofield("RT")
Call uiprof.SelectAll
Call uiprof.Copy
Call uiprof.Close
' later on the clipboard will be pasted into the word document
```

Any ideas what could be the cause here? I am setting up an environment with XP, MS Office 2010 and Notes tonight to check it out that it is not caused by Windows 7.

Comment: The only solution is to save your RTF content as MIME/HTML, save this to another field in the document and read this via VBA. Paste the content in your document and let Word do the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Windows 7 machine is 64 bit, take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416308/is-a-comexception-of-0x80040154-always-class-not-registered).  Note that those refer to the COM classes (lotus.*), and you are using the OLE classes (notes.*), but I believe the 64/32 bit issue applies to both.

Comment: Good point, never thought about it. My machine is 64bit, BUT the customers machines are 32bit. I looked for an option in VBA editor in Word where to set an option to compile with 32bit - nothing found. Maybe this 32/64 issue doesn't bother in "pure" VBA with OLE?