# send Email from lotus notes with attachment using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I wanted to send Emails with attachments from lotus notes.

I tried this below code, it is showing error:

Error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in App_Web_sendemail.aspx.cdcab7d2.s2ysjl2c.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Database open failed (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx!!names.nsf)
```

Code:

```
Domino.NotesSession nSession = new Domino.NotesSession();
        nSession.Initialize("bbau0862"); //Password

        Domino.NotesDatabase nDatabase =
  nSession.GetDatabase("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "names.nsf");

        //If the database is not already open then open it. 
        if (!nDatabase.IsOpen)
        {
            nDatabase.Open();
        }

        Domino.NotesDocument nDocument = nDatabase.CreateDocument();
        /*create string variable that will be passed to function. This way we setup To field value*/
        string[] recipients =
          {"abc@gmail.com", "xyz@gmail.com"};

        //setup Form
        nDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
        nDocument.ReplaceItemValue("SentTo", recipients); //To field
        nDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", "Message subject"); //message subject
        nDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Body", "Something in the message body"); //set body text
        nDocument.SaveMessageOnSend = true; //save message after it's sent
        nDocument.Send(false, recipients); //send
```

please tell me how to send lotus notes email with attachments in asp.net.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code failed to open the database 'names.nsf'. Before you ask about how to send an email with attachments, you need to figure out why your code failed to open the database.

Some of the possible explanations for that are: you failed to connect to the server, you don't have access to the server, or you don't have access to the database. You need to check all those things.

What IBM Lotus code is installed on the machine where your code is running? Is the Notes client code installed or is the Domino server code installed? One or the other has to be, and if it's the server code it has to be the 32 bit version because IBM doesn't support 64-bit COM classes for Domino.

You need to check whether the code can connect to the server 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx'. Both the client and the server have Trace features that you can use to check that. See [help for client trace](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTWP_8.5.3/com.ibm.notes85.help.doc/pref_trace_connection_t.html)) or [help for server trace](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21247723).

You also need to check whether the current user id (the one that corresponds to the password "bbau0862" that you are passing into the `Initialize()` method, and which must be the current id -- pointed to by the keyfilename or serverkeyfilename entries in the notes.ini file of the Notes client or Domino server installation on the -- has access to the server 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' and to the database 'names.nsf'. (If it has access to the server, it ought to have access to names.nsf, but if it's some sort of 'special' id that was given to you specifically for your application, you really ought to check!  Both of these are easy to check using a Notes client and that ID.

Answer (score -1):

it happened to me i get this error with Domino using c# or powershell.
i think you try use a 32 bit domino COM composant(64 bit doesn't exist for domino client) in a 64 bit application.
it mean domino composant will work in a *86 powershell console when it throw this error in a 64 bit powershell console.

solution i'm afraid is to recompile project for *86 !

view here for more detail:
[Is a COMException of 0x80040154 always 'Class not registered'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416308/is-a-comexception-of-0x80040154-always-class-not-registered)

so i point you in my experience using domino COM is very bugy you better have your domino team make a webservice of user info.

using domino for exemple force everything run as x86.
and in a client side app the COM will crash at any c# unintented error kiling in the same time the lotus notes client of your users(BOSS?).

Comment: That's not the error. He got "Database open failed (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx!!names.nsf)". The code never would have gotten that far if it had failed to load the class.